# About Auto Filtering in Excel

Tags: excel

I have table with two columns. Team name and % win .
    Is there a way you can use Auto Filtering or filtering to list the teams which have won more than 20% ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Highlight your table, turn on Autofilter, and set the criteria to where win % "is greater than" 20% for the win percentage column.

Comment: Is this right way to do it,  so I click on on the column and enter   Sheet1!$A$1 > 20  for criteria ?

Comment: You don't need to enter a cell reference.  It automatically applies your criterion to every cell in the column.  Using the filtration drop-down, choose `(Custom...)` filtering, choose `is greater than`, and enter `20%` (which it will auto-convert to 0.20).